# Passing multiple Eval() to a JavaScript function from ASPX

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to pass multiple `Eval()` arguments to a JavaScript function from an `.aspx` file, but I keep getting compiler errors.  I am new to JavaScript and have never really used `Eval()` before.  Where am I going wrong?

**NB**:  The line shown below is actually all on one line, but is wrapped here for clarity:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>'
    OnClick='javascript:ShowEventDetails'
    CommandArgument='<%#
        Eval("EventID").ToString()          & Eval("Title").ToString() &
        Eval("Location").ToString()         & Eval("StartTime").ToString() &
        Eval("Description").ToString()      & Eval("Link").ToString() &
        Eval("ContactFirstName").ToString() & Eval("ContactLastName").ToString() &
        Eval("ContactEmail").ToString()     & Eval("InsertionTime").ToString() &
        Eval("EventAdmin").ToString()%>); ' />
```

Are there better ways of doing this? If so, what are they?

Comment: Let me know if the answer I gave helped you.

Answer (score 1):

[OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclick.aspx) is a property on the control which expects a reference to an event handler method. Putting JavaScript in the OnClick property will not work.

If you want to execute arbitrary JavaScript when the button is clicked, use [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx). I presume you want to pass the evals into ShowEventDetails as arguments (formatted for readability):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title")%>' 
    OnClientClick='ShowEventDetails("<%# Eval("EventID").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("Title").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("Location").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("StartTime").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("Description").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("Link").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("ContactFirstName").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("ContactLastName").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("ContactEmail").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("InsertionTime").ToString() %>",
        "<%# Eval("EventAdmin").ToString() %>");' />
```

Essentially you are constructing one long string:

```
ShowEventDetails('123','Event Title','New York' ... etc ...
```

Which is executed in JS when the LinkButton is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

The compiler now complains that the server tag is not well formatted.

Comment: @Dhruv OK, this method of constructing arguments is a bit error-prone since there are so many places for syntax typos. I've redone it and verified it works.

Comment: @Rex
Thanks.
This is what I get from the page source. Do you still think we can work around this?
<a onclick="ShowEventDetails(&quot;<%# Eval(&quot;EventID&quot;).ToString() %>&quot;,
        &quot;<%# Eval(&quot;Title&quot;).ToString() %>&quot;,
 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to set the `OnClientClick` property in the code-behind, like so:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); //Instantiate the linkbutton wherever you need to
```

Once you do, use `String.Format` to put your items into the `OnClientClick` property.

```
lb.OnClientClick = String.Format("javascript:ShowEventDetails
( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}', '{10}');", 
  EventID.ToString(), Title.ToString(), Location.ToString(), StartTime.ToString(), 
  Description.ToString(), Link.ToString(), ContactFirstName.ToString(),
  ContactLastName.ToString(), ContactEmail.ToString(), InsertionTime.ToString(),
  EventAdmin.ToString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to pass multiple parameter from aspx client, sample code is given below

> Use two double quotes (*+ ",""" + Eval("xxx").ToString() + """*) if you want to pass a string parameter

```
OnClientClick='<%#"javascript:return OpenDetailsPage(" + Eval("xxx").ToString() + ",""" + Eval("xxx").ToString() + """," _
                                                + Eval("xxx").ToString() + "," + Eval("xxx").ToString() + "," + Eval("xxx").ToString() + "," _
                                                + Eval("xxx").ToString() + ",""" + Eval("xxx").ToString() + """,this);"%> '
```

Answer (score 0):

`Eval` is **Evil** try this Life Saving Code

```
onClick=='<%# string.Format("javascript:ShowEventDetails({0},{1},{2});return false;", Eval("Title"), Eval("Location"), Eval("StartTime")) %>'
```