# Passing multiple Eval parameters to a JavaScript function from ASPX

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I already know how it works with a single parameter

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("confirm_ticket({0});return false;",DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.idAgir"))%> '
```

but is it possible to pass 2 parameters?

Comment: Yes its possible, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748080/passing-multiple-eval-to-a-javascript-function-from-aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose functions is...

```
<script language = 'javascript'>
   function confirm_ticket(ID, ID1)
   {

   }
</script>

OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("confirm_ticket({0},{1});
return false;",Eval("idAgir"), Eval("idAgir"))%> '
```

---

Alternatively you can move in `ItemBoundData` and there also the string can be concatenated.